# Adjacent Close values

Tags: market-data

I've seen a number of papers and writings mentioning "adjacent close" values. Such as: [1],[2], [3]. But I haven't been able to find a definition of the term. Can anyone help? I'm actually beginning to wonder whether they are actually thinking of "adjusted close" values, which is a term one can easily find a definition for!

[1] https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340698512_Stock_Closing_Price_Prediction_using_Machine_Learning_Techniques

[2] http://www.ijirae.com/volumes/Vol7/iss-3/35.MRITSCE10114.pdf

[3] https://rpubs.com/petermokua/846559

Answer (score 5):

I’m convinced you’re right about this. Note that these paper don’t appear to have been published in reputable journals and from a quick skim seem to be low on useful content.

In conclusion, if I were you I wouldn’t spend much time on these.

Comment: i glanced at the rpub link that bob sent and it's clearly a typo in that one. this would lead me to think that it's also a typo in the others.

Comment: I've never heard of "adjacent close" - and I've been doing data for 20+ years now.  There's some pretty serious selection bias in the data used for these papers and vague conclusions too.